# SQL Server : merge 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table ONE with data:

```
Id      v1   V2   
-----------------
1       10   100     
2       15   150     
3       20   200
```

and a table TWO with data:

```
Id     v3   V4   
------------------
1    1000    1000     
2    1500   15000     
3    2000   20000  
4     800   30000
```

I want to get this result:

```
Id      v1   V2     v3      V4
----------------------------------
1       10   100    1000    1000   
2       15   150    1500   15000   
3       20   200    2000   20000 
4       null null    800   30000
```

I tried this SQL code:

```
SELECT *
FROM [One]
FULL OUTER JOIN [Two] ON [One].ID = [Two].ID
```

Comment: Does the query you have not do what you want? Could you explain how it doesn’t meet your requirements?

Comment: Could you create a view that joins the 2 tables or do you really need a table?

Comment: `from [two] left join [one]`

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something but I think you just need left join

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TWO] t
LEFT JOIN [ONE] o ON o.Id = t.Id
```